# Looking for video casts of smart people administrating linux servers

Tags: linux, video

I'm a windows developer and just switched my hosted website over to a VPS to teach me some linux administration.

I would like to find some video tutorials that I can watch which just someone doing various common tasks on various linux flavors: CentOS, debian, Suse, e.g.

- setting up a firewall
- setting up cron jobs
- just seeing the commands they use, the bash scripts they have, etc.
- how they organize their files
- how they set up DNS, email, etc.
- upgrading from PHP 5.2 to PHP 5.3
- setting up a virtual host in apache
- using pine or vi or emacs, etc.
- how they install/remove software
- how they deal with problems that come up, etc.
- etc., etc. etc.

I'm not looking for polished video tutorials, just knowledgable people who turn on a screencast recorder and solve real problems and talk about it as they do it.

Does anyone know of a good source of videos like this?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.howtoforge.com/

Here is a tutorial site on many how-to's in linux.  They even have different flavors of linux and many of the resources you are looking for.

Also, these are kinda poorly organized, but there is some useful info.

http://www.faqs.org/docs/howtos1.html
http://www.faqs.org/docs/howtos2.html
http://www.faqs.org/docs/howtos3.html

You kind of have to search around in those sites to find what you are looking for. Always remember to try google in more detail if all else fails. Add as many keywords as you can think of from the linux distro you are using to the packages you want to install.

And when it comes to videos, surprisingly I have good luck with youtube.com. There is a lot of content on there now and lots of educational resources.